# How to promote personal dashboard to global dashboard?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9

A business user has created a personal dashboard which is now become main dashboard for the company. I have a request to make this personal dashboard a global dashboard.

I have tried all options I can see in customize system. Unless I create a new  dashboard and try to match that dashboard I cannot see an option to copy or to promote personal dashboard to a global dashboard.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: Thanks Arun for your prompt reply below. Unfortunately, I have not find anyway to do this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right! Unfortunately there’s no way to convert the user Dashboard (Personal Dashboard) into global Dashboard (System Dashboard) or vice versa. You have to recreate the views & Dashboard from scratch.

**Update**:

Atleast found [this useful info for promoting](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmdevdownunder/posts/convert-personal-view-to-system-view) "Personal views" into "System views".

The [Managed solution](https://github.com/rajyraman/Personal-View-to-System-View/releases) can be imported into CRM to do the same.

[image]

On a side note, If anyone else "Personal view" has to be owned/recreated/assigned to Service account/Admin account - then use this XrmToolBox plugin: [Personal Artefact Manager](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/NZ.XrmToolbox.PersonalArtefactManager/)